# Wagtail: Filter Pages by a ForeignKey

Tags: django, wagtail

Using [Wagtail](https://wagtail.io) I want to get a QuerySet of `Page`s whose specific subclass have a certain ForeignKey to a `Snippet`.

```
from django.db import models
from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.snippets.models import register_snippet

@register_snippet
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)

class ArticlePage(Page):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(
        'Organization',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+'
    )
```

So, how would I get a QuerySet of all `Page`s whose associated `ArticlePage` has an `Organisation` with an `id` of `1`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ArticlePage.objects.filter(organisation__id=1)
```

This will give you a queryset of `ArticlePage` objects, which is usually preferable to a queryset of `Page` objects as it will give you all of the functionality of Page as well as any additional fields and methods defined on ArticlePage. If for some reason you need them to be basic `Page` objects, you can use:

```
Page.objects.filter(articlepage__organisation__id=1)
```

Comment: Thanks! I do need `Page`s, to be consistent with some other queries. I didn't realise Pages have fields named after their subclass!