# Wagtail filter child pages by a ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I'm using [Wagtail](https://wagtail.io/), and I want to filter a selection of child pages by a Foreign Key. I've tried the following and I get the error `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'use_case' into field` when I try `children = self.get_children().specific().filter(use_case__slug=slug)`:

```py
class AiLabResourceMixin(models.Model):
  parent_page_types = ['AiLabResourceIndexPage']
  use_case = models.ForeignKey(AiLabUseCase, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
  content_panels = ArticlePage.content_panels + [
    FieldPanel('use_case', widget=forms.Select())
  ]

  class Meta:
    abstract = True

class AiLabCaseStudy(AiLabResourceMixin, ArticlePage):
  pass

class AiLabBlogPost(AiLabResourceMixin, ArticlePage):
  pass

class AiLabExternalLink(AiLabResourceMixin, ArticlePage):
  pass

class AiLabResourceIndexPage(RoutablePageMixin, BasePage):
  parent_page_types = ['AiLabHomePage']
  subpage_types = ['AiLabCaseStudy', 'AiLabBlogPost', 'AiLabExternalLink']
  max_count = 1

  @route(r'^$')
  def all_resources(self, request):
    children = self.get_children().specific()

    return render(request, 'ai_lab/ai_lab_resource_index_page.html', {
      'page': self,
      'children': children,
    })

  @route(r'^([a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*)/$')
  def filter_by_use_case(self, request, slug):
    children = self.get_children().specific().filter(use_case__slug=slug)

    return render(request, 'ai_lab/ai_lab_resource_index_page.html', {
      'page': self,
      'children': children,
    })
```

I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53394289/wagtail-filter-pages-by-a-foreignkey), but this assumes I only have one type of page I want to filter. Using something like `AiLabCaseStudy.objects.filter(use_case__slug=slug)` works, but this only returns `AiLabCaseStudy`s, not `AiLabBlogPost`s or `AiLabExternalLink`s.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the database level, there is no efficient way to run the filter against all page types at once. Since `AiLabResourceMixin` is defined as `abstract = True`, this class has no representation of its own within the database - instead, the `use_case` field is defined separately for each of `AiLabCaseStudy`, `AiLabBlogPost` and `AiLabExternalLink`. As a result, there's no way for Django or Wagtail to turn `.filter(use_case__slug=slug)` into a SQL query, since `use_case` refers to three different places in the database.

A couple of possible ways around this:

- If your data model allows, restructure it to use [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) - this looks fairly similar to your current definition, except without the `abstract = True`:

  ```
  class AiLabResourcePage(ArticlePage):
    use_case = models.ForeignKey(AiLabUseCase, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

  class AiLabCaseStudy(AiLabResourcePage):
    pass

  class AiLabBlogPost(AiLabResourcePage):
    pass

  class AiLabExternalLink(AiLabResourcePage):
    pass
  ```

  `AiLabResourcePage` will then exist in its own right in the database, and you can query its `use_case` field with an expression like: `AiLabResourcePage.objects.child_of(self).filter(use_case__slug=slug).specific()`. There'll be a small performance impact here, since Django has to pull data from one additional table to construct these page objects.
- Run a preliminary query on each specific page type to retrieve the matching page IDs, before running the final query with `specific()`:

  ```
  case_study_ids = list(AiLabCaseStudy.objects.child_of(self).filter(use_case__slug=slug).values_list('id', flat=True))
  blog_post_ids = list(AiLabBlogPost.objects.child_of(self).filter(use_case__slug=slug).values_list('id', flat=True))
  external_link_ids = list(AiLabExternalLink.objects.child_of(self).filter(use_case__slug=slug).values_list('id', flat=True))
  children = Page.objects.filter(id__in=(case_study_ids + blog_post_ids + external_link_ids)).specific()
  ```

Comment: Ah, nice work. That seems to have got it. I'm new to Django / Wagtail, so the internals are pretty much a mystery to me. I usually shy away from Single Table Inheritence, but I think it works well for this use case. Cheers!

Comment: Hmmmm... Looks like I may have spoken too soon. I've tried to add another column to a child model like so:

```python
class AiLabExternalResource(AiLabResourcePage):
  url = models.URLField()

  content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
    FieldPanel('url', widget=forms.URLInput())
  ]
```

And now I get the error `can't set attribute` when trying to create the page. Is this something I just can't do with this method?

Comment: You'll need to make sure the panel for `use_case` is present in your content_panels definition too. But if that's not the issue, I'd need to see the full code and error trace, and at that point you should really ask this as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`children = self.get_children().filter(use_case__slug=slug).specific()`

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work - regardless of where `specific()` appears in the expression, the queryset that the `filter` applies to will be the Page queryset returned from `get_children()`, and the `use_case` field isn't available from there.